# Adjoint pair between Category of Chain Complexes

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I have to show that if (L,R) is an adjoint pair between two abelian category **A** and **B**, then  L and R induces
**L**:  **Ch(A)**->**Ch(B)**
**R**:  **Ch(B)** ->**Ch(A)**

(where **Ch(A)** is the category of chain complexes in **A**)

such that (**L**,**R**) is an adjoint pair.

I know I have to use the naturality of the isomorphism given by (L,R) but I'am a bit confused..Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Here $(L, R)$ is an adjoint pair of _additive_ functors between **A** and **B**?

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot to say it.

Comment: I propose it may be easier to prove a more general theorem: let $\mathcal{C}$ be a preadditive category, and $L : \mathcal{A} \rightleftarrows \mathcal{B} : R$ be an adjunction of preadditive categories. Then the induced functors (i.e. given by composition) give an adjunction $L^\mathcal{C} : \mathcal{A}^\mathcal{C} \rightleftarrows \mathcal{B}^\mathcal{C} : R^\mathcal{C}$, where by the exponential I mean the category of additive functors.

Comment: @EricCanton: if a functor between Abelian categories has adjoint, it must preserve finite biproducts (=products=coproducts), so in the end it must be additive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $L$ is a functor, if $f: M \to N$ is a morphism in **A** then $L(f): L(M) \to L(N)$ is a morphism in **B**. Thus, if we have a chain complex

$$ (M_\bullet, d) =(\cdots \to M_i \to M_{i-1} \to \cdots) $$
the only reasonable candidate for $\mathbf{L}(M_\bullet, d^M)$ is

$$(L(M_\bullet), L(d)) = (\cdots \to L(M_i) \to L(M_{i-1}) \to \cdots),$$

where of course I'm applying $L$ to the all of the morphisms $d_i: M_i \to M_{i-1}$, too. We have to check is  this again a chain complex and that composition of morphisms works, but this is straightforward:

by virtue of being a functor, $L(d)^2 = L(d^2)$, and since $L$ is additive we know $L(0) = 0$.

composition of chain maps works fine essentially because chain maps in **Ch(A)** are built out of morphisms in **A**, and $L$ is a functor on **A**. It's a routine check, but do it if it's not totally clear.

As you may guess, $\mathbf{R}$ is obtained in the same way.

For the adjunction, try starting with a chain map $\phi \in \mathrm{Hom}_\mathbf{Ch(B)}(\mathbf{L}(M_\bullet, d), (N_\bullet, d'))$, use that this gives us a sequence $\phi_i \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{B}}(L(M_i), N_i)$, use this to get $\psi_i \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{A}}(M_i, R(N_i))$ by the original adjunction, and then prove that $\psi = (\dots, \psi_i, \dots)$ link up together to give a chain map $(M_\bullet, d) \to (R(N_\bullet), R(d'))$.